# Does Poison Null Byte still exist in .Net 4.5

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, vb.net, code-injection

Short question, I have been trying to sandbox a theoretical Poison Null Byte attack on one of our .NET 4.5 systems without any success. I have seen information that it was patched in .NET 2.0 but was not sure if it patched on all instances. 
We use all of the standard ASP.NET WebForm's/MVC/WebAPI libraries.

The sample I am using without any effect is:

```
dim val as string = Server.MapPath("~/FileA.exe%00.pdf")
```

Is anyone aware of any instances that it may still exist? Or is it completely removed?

Thanks,

Comment: If a security vulnerability was removed in .NET 2.0, I highly doubt it is back in with .NET 4.5.

Comment: Thanks Eric, I believe that is an obvious assumption. There was never any information on which posix functions were patched, and working with my company on a new app and seeing this as a previous flaw in .NET I am trying to make sure there is nowhere it still exists. What I am after is if there is any known instances of libraries still vulnerable to this.